# Webscraping issue

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to do some **webscraping**. The main idea of the following code is to get the urls inside the output of a serach in a website. I've been having problems with this code:

```
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL_WEB_URB = "https://adondevivir.com"

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
web = scraper.get("https://www.adondevivir.com/departamentos-en-alquiler-en-jesus-maria-ordenado-por-fechaonline-descendente-pagina-3.html")

depa_info = BeautifulSoup(web.text, "lxml")
publicaciones = depa_info.select(".postingCard")

pub_links = [URL_WEB_URB + ref["data-to-posting"] for ref in publicaciones]

print(pub_links)
```

I get the following error:

> ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.adondevivir.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /departamentos-en-alquiler-en-jesus-maria-ordenado-por-fechaonline-descendente-pagina-3.html (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired')))

I've tracked the error to the line

```
web = scraper.get("https://www.adondevivir.com/departamentos-en-alquiler-en-jesus-maria-ordenado-por-fechaonline-descendente-pagina-3.html")
```

But I can't seem to fix it. I've tried changing the URL (https to http), but it wasn't that. I've searched for answers but I haven't found one regarding this kind of code.

Comment: I've just runned this code in another PC and it works. It must have something to do with my internet connection. I'm not sure exactly what.

Comment: Maybe the website blocked you for making to many requests?

Comment: It showed me that error on the first try. But it could be somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found a solution. I hads to apply a proxy to the scraper to avoid the network from blocking it.